# -webkit-overflow-scrolling polyfill or feature detection

Tags: ios, html, mobile, css

`-webkit-overflow-scrolling` is new to iOS 5. I'm looking for a CSS polyfill or a method rather than user agent reading for detecting if this feature is available. Modernizer don't detect this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Modernizr doesn't detect the property by default, but you can add your own test to it.

Just call this code anywhere:

```
Modernizr.addTest('overflowscrolling', function() {
    return Modernizr.testAllProps("overflowScrolling");
});
```

after the call, your `body` element will either have a `overflowscrolling` or a `no-overflowscrolling` class and you can check the support against `Modernizr.overflowscrolling`.